# How to enforce keycloak policies with krakend

Tags: go, keycloak, api-gateway, identity-management, krakend

We want to protect krakend endpoints by using the keycloak policies.

From the keycloak documentation ([here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_enforcer_overview)) it's possible by using the adapters, but there is none for Go

If krakend cannot do this, please advice a tool that does.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right place or whether e.g. superuser.com or serverfault.com would be more appropriate. In any case, asking for opinions ("Is it even the concern of an api gateway ?") or tools is off-topic here.